# Android MotionEvent pressure unit of measurement

Tags: android, motionevent

I am using the getPressure(index) method from the MotionEvent instance to get a value of the pressure applied to screen.

I am trying to figure out how to convert that value to at least an approximation of a standard measurement unit.

in Android the pressure value is a float ranging from 0 to 1. I need to express it in Newtons in some way.
From what i understood this is different across devices so its not possible get a really precise unit measurement but i am fine with an approximation.

Like what amount in newtons is normal for a stylus touching the screen on full force (the device measuring 1.0f of pressure)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the max value, since you can get 1f with different strengths. I would try - put a known-weight appropriate object on the screen or on your finger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect screen pressure on android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538513/how-to-detect-screen-pressure-on-android)

Comment: Its not a duplicate since that resolves a crash, i am looking for a way to figure out a decent range of force values when using the stylus. i don't care about accuracy that much because i know i cannot achieve a really accurate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only guess, and know that the results will be affected by huge uncertainity. Solutions I see:

1. Put an object of appropriate, known weight on the screen. Don't know about screens, but if it needs human skin to trigger the event, you can put your finger on the screen (making no strength on it) and then put some object on your finger.
2. Take a stylus, and by debugging learn how much force you need to get a `0.5f` result. Then take a scale (foreign speaker here; I mean the tool that measures weights..?) and apply the same pressure on it with the stylus, and read the results.

In both cases, you can have a single map point (e.g., `0.5f -> 10 N`), and then assume a linear dependency (knowing also that `0f -> 0 N`) to fill the whole range.

With some patience you can fill different values too - I would not expect the relation to be linear actually.

Comment: I did use an object of 1KG attached to the stylus and held it on top of the screen, it measured around 0.5f. So i am assuming that the maximum measurable pressure on screen is 20 Newtons. As you said the simplest way of transforming any value on this scale is linear so i used that. 0.5f -> 10N, etc... I know it is not accurate in real world applications but it does provide a realistic reference scale for my use case.

Comment: It might be a good estimate. However, I would give a try to objects of 2Kg or 0.5Kg and see how the model stands. Really curious about how you attached 1Kg to the stylus! :-)

Comment: Don't ask :) hahah. the thing had a hole on the bottom for a screw. the stylus top was a fit inside.

Answer (score 0):

`getPressure` returns a value 0-1 because the way pressure is calculated is device-dependant. Some devices will calculate the value from how much of the area of your finger is touching the screen. So from that it's probably not possible to convert to newtons in a way which will work on multiple Android devices unless you write a solution for each one.

Comment: I just need it to work on 1 device. 1 specific android device model, i need to find a good reference value and use that as a scale. hope that makes sense? Specifically how much force the stylus makes when the pressure value is 1.0f. What is a reasonable value. Like 1N, 0.1N, 0.001N etc?

Comment: In that case you'll just need to run some tests on that one device. Output the value of getPressure onto the screen while you place different weights onto the screen. If you want to be more accurate you'd have to take altitude altitude into account. 1 kg mass will be attracted toward the Earth by a force of 9.81 Newtons at sea level.