# Is there a way to detect a pressure power on screen?

Tags: android

I need to check the power with which the user pressing the screen, like force touch or 3D touch.

Googling it, I saw that Android Q will support deep touch. It looks like a new constant added in Android Q:
`public static final int CLASSIFICATION_DEEP_PRESS`

So, the first, is it like a hardware feature on the phone, not software, so that only some phones could be tested on it? Second, is it true that until Android Q released, we can't measure screen pressing power? If it's not, how can I achieve it now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538513/how-to-detect-screen-pressure-on-android

Comment: AndroDevil, I saw this question. the `getPressure()` method always returns 1 on my device when I press my view with any power. Is it because my phone doesn't support force touch? And on another phone which supports it, this should work fine?

Comment: Did you tested on any other devices?

Comment: Yes, I've tested this on 2 devices (I don't have more). But I found that there is a small bunch of devices that claimed to support deep touch, and my devices (both of them are Xiaomi's production) are not in that list.